# why doesn't python3 cElementTree honor <import file=""/> in xml file?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to get cElementTree to recurse into xml import elements.
I presume I'm missing something simple here.

`<import file="xmlfile_imported.xml"/>`

code I'm using

```
try:
    import cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
  try:
    # Python 2.5 need to import a different module
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
  except ImportError:
    exit_err("Failed to import cElementTree from any known place")
def_file="xmlfile.xml"
try:
    tree = ET.parse(open(def_file, "r"))
    root = tree.getroot()
except:
    exit_err("Unable to open and parse input definition file: " + def_file)

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib);
```

Using this code I will only see the content of the xmlfile.xml but not the content of xmlfile_imported.xml.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would <import> include xmlfile_imported.xml? What tool does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to imagine that `<import file="..."/>` is some kind of directive to an XML parser. It isn't. It's just part of the application-specific vocabularity. If you were using XInclude, that would be a different question.